# Properly extract data from JSON string

Tags: python, json

I need to extract the following info as a table from JSON string:

[image]

```
flightId     lat         lon  
657853226    39.588      -123.6683 
...
```

This is how I started to solve the task:

```
request=Request('...')
response_flights = urlopen(request)
fn = response_flights.read()
flights = json.loads(fn)
flights = pd.DataFrame(json_normalize(flights['flightPositions']))
```

Buthow can I save positions in a `DataFrame` along with `flightId`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say I have an input file `input.json` that looks like

```
{
  "flightPositions": [
      {
        "flightId": 65782839,
        "positions": [
          {
            "lon": -123.6683,
            "lat": 39.588
          },
          {
            "lon": -123.734,
            "lat": 39.6446
          }
        ]
      }
  ]
}
```

I can then build up a pandas `DataFrame` from a list of `Series` objects, like so:

```
import json
import pandas

data = json.load(open('input.json', 'r'))

flightdata = []
for flight_position in data['flightPositions']:
    flight_id = flight_position['flightId']
    for position in flight_position['positions']:
        position['flightId'] = flight_id
        series = pandas.Series(position)
        flightdata.append(series)

df = pandas.DataFrame(flightdata)
print(df)
```

This will give me:

```
   flightId      lat       lon
0  65782839  39.5880 -123.6683
1  65782839  39.6446 -123.7340
```